# When using Bumblebee, how do I query the current state of the nvidia card?

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee

I am using ubuntu 13.10, and have bumblebee installed. I can see that `bumblebeed` is running.

I would like to test whether the NVidia card is currently powered. Can I do this?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: @Salem thanks for reminding me. Your solution is the one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that using `cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch`:

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch 
0000:01:00.0 OFF
```

If for some reason it stays on when you are not using it, check your Bumblebee configuration (stored in `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`), more precisely the `PMMethod` value.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Nvidia card is disabled in Bumblebee.

But you can run a program with your Nvidia card using `optirun <program name>`.

If you installed primus, you can use `primusrun <program name>`.

Example:
`glxgears` for FPS without Nvidia.
`optirun glxgears` for FPS with Nvidia.